# Can I run Overwatch on Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I'm considering installing Ubuntu on my new PC, the only reason I got the new PC was to play [Overwatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overwatch_(video_game)) because it wouldn't run on my old laptop.

If I install Ubuntu on my new PC will I be able to install/run Overwatch? I really need to know because I don't want to spend $150 on Windows 10 if I can run it on this for free.

Comment: What is Overwatch?

Comment: I don't know if you edited that in just now since I didn't notice it earlier but windows 10 is still free on Microsoft website with a full iso file

Answer (score 2):

Running Overwatch in Wine is doable.  It's not reliable though, and you'll lose an average of 5-10 fps vs Windows 10.  You're better off dual-booting.  Even Steam games made for Linux tend to run worse than their Windows counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu and leave space left to install Windows on so you have both operating system. Or you can run Windows in a virtual box. There are programs like Wine that can run Windows programs in Ubuntu by converting DirectX into OpenGL but it has some issues so I wouldn't use it for graphic heavy things like games. Some games are avaliable on Ubuntu like Ark Survival Evolved(which I love but only have on Xbox1)

Comment: I just got done installing Windows after resizing my partion so I can stream xbox one to it. If you need tips on installing them both feel free to ask since I've installed them both about 3 times now